# Iframe failure when embedding Google Scholar web in other web using Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, google-scholar

I have my own personal portfolio ([modestomata.com](https://www.modestomata.com)) and I would like to include in some of my pages an iframe with other webs. For instance, when I try to embed this website (http://www.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com) in the `iframe` it works nice:

```
<iframe src="http://www.vivaelsoftwarelibre.com" width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
    <iframe>
```

However, when I try to embed my personal Google Scholar page (https://scholar.google.es/citations?user=v4UtSKUAAAAJ&hl=en) in my portfolio page, I get a blank iframe.

```html
<iframe src="https://scholar.google.es/citations?user=v4UtSKUAAAAJ&hl=en" width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
<iframe>
```

So, how can I make the iframe to display my Google Scholar web in other page?

Comment: If you check dev tools you will see "Refused to display 'https://scholar.google.es/citations?user=v4UtSKUAAAAJ&hl=en' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

Comment: Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: X-Frame-Options is a response header sent from their server.

Comment: So, there is no possibility, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this site (https://iframely.com/embed/https%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.com%2Fcitations%3Fuser%3DgA_qrcUAAAAJ%26hl%3Den%26oi%3Dao) to generate embedded code for your google scholar account. Then use "advanced iframe plugin" to include the generated code to your site. Alternatively, use HTML widget to add those generated HTML codes to your WordPress site.